# Interesting question regarding proof for a number to be composite.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $n^4+4^n$ is not a prime for any natural number $n>1$.

***My Approach:***

Suppose $n^4+4^n$ is prime.

It is evident that $n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for $n^4+4^n$ to be prime.
$$n\equiv 1\pmod 2\Rightarrow 4^n\equiv (-1)\pmod 5$$
Suppose $\gcd (n,5)=1$. Then by euler's identity:

$$\phi (5)=4\Rightarrow n^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$$
$$\therefore n^4+4^n\equiv 0\pmod 5$$
Thus $n^4+4^n$ is never a prime if $n$ is not a multiple of $5$.

Now I seem to be struck in proving the same for when $n$ is mutiple of $5$.

Please help and also please provide suggestions.

***THANKS***

Comment: $x^4 + 4 y^4 = (x^2 + 2xy + 2 y^2)(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Sophie Germain's Identity kills it :

$n^4+4^n=((n+2^k)^2+4^k))((n-2^k)^2+4^k))$, when $n=2k+1$ and you can figure it out that $n$ must be odd in your case.

Comment: That definitely is a good way to solve this question. But is there a way to prove it without using sophie germain identity?

Comment: This problem is usually proposed to see how to use this identity. So I never seen a solution without it...